# PHP setcookie not working on virtual directory

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have an ajax call that does this:

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['T1']))
    {
        $expire = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3650 + time();  //10 years
    setcookie('T1', 'Y', $expire, '/', false);
    echo 'a';
    }

    echo $_COOKIE['T1'];
```

This code above runs fine. The first time through it echo's 'a' when the cookie gets set and thhe next time it doesn't on outputs 'Y' for the cookie variable.  All this is done in one page.

But I have another page in which I output $_COOKIE['T1']; and it's empty.

I have my site running on my own machine and have set up the windows/apache host files so that my 127.0.0.1 host is myexample.com.

Why isn't it still working on the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
setcookie('T1', 'Y', $expire, '/');
```

Refer to the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: nevermind,...apparently you can't have a '/' in your cookie key, which works on the page that sets the cookie but not anywhere else